# Adding Gradle plugin tasks to build invocation

Tags: gradle, groovy, cobertura, gradle-plugin

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.saliman.cobertura' version '2.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile(
        'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'
    )

    testCompile(
        'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    )
}

cobertura {
    coverageCheckTotalLineRate = 95

    coverageCheckHaltOnFailure = true
}
```

As you can see I have set up the [Gradle Cobertura](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin) plugin. Typically build my application via:

```
./gradlew build
```

But to run Cobertura, I have to run a totally different invocation:

```
./gradlew cobertura coberturaCheck
```

I want to condense these so that running `./gradlew build` also runs these 2 Cobertura tasks.

**How can I reconfigure my build so that `./gradlew build` also runs `./gradlew cobertura coberturaCheck` *after* all tests have finished running?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a quick look at the sources of the Cobertura plugin.
The dependencies that the tests must run befor Cobertura and so on are all correctly set up by the plugin, so the right order should be taken as granted.

Actually it is the case that all tasks of type `Test` are set up in such a way that the Cobertura Report generation is always run after them as well as the coverage checking. Those tasks are simply disabled by default.

Adding `coberturaCheck` to the task graph to be executed enables all cobertura tasks including the coverage check task.

Adding `cobertura` to the task graph enables all cobertura tasks except of the coverage check task. So if you already added `coberturaCheck` to the task graph, adding `cobertura` has the only effect that it depends on all tasks of type `Test`.

As in your project the only task of type `Test` is the task called `test` which is already depended on from `check` which is depended on from `build`, it is enough to depend on `coberturaCheck` to enable the cobertura tasks, so just do `build.dependsOn coberturaCheck` in your build file, or if you like it more `check.dependsOn coberturaCheck`.

If you nevertheless want to depend on `cobertura` also, because you might fear that tasks of type `Test` are added in the future that are not depended on by task `check`, you can of course also do that. This would look like `build.dependsOn tasks.cobertura, coberturaCheck` or `check.dependsOn tasks.cobertura, coberturaCheck`.

The extra `tasks.` for `cobertura` is necessary, because there is also a project extensions called `cobertura` which would be taken before looking for a task called `cobertura` so you must explicitly state that you want the task here.